# When is this matrix positive definite?

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

A square matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is defined by

$$M_{i,j} = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } i=j \\ p & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

where $M_{i,j}$ denotes the $(i,j)$-th entry. What is the "iff" condition for $p$ to make the matrix $M$ positive definite?

Comment: This matrix is a symmetric matrix with 1's on the diagonal and $p$ elsewhere. A matrix is positive definite if it is symmetric and all its eigenvalues are positive, and if all of its pivots are positive. It is clear that if $p=0$, we have a positive definite matrix (the identity). Try row reducing and see what happens to the pivots, or ask "for some value of $p$, what will the eigenvalues be?". A good starting point for this is to find $det(M_{2x2}-tI_2)$, or the charachteristic polynomial of $M_{2x2}$ in respect to $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Given a matrix $M_{n\times n}$ defined as proposed, its eigenvalues are

$$
\{1-p,\cdots,1-p,1+(n-1)p\}
$$
so the conditions are

$$
\cases{
1-p > 0\\
1+(n-1)p > 0
}
$$

or

$$
-\frac{1}{n-1}< p < 1
$$

Comment: And the degenerate eigenvalue seems to have the wrong sign.